# I want to open dialog from one component and close it after 3s but I got an error. I follow angular material UI documentation but nothing will work

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I used Angular version 11 and angular material version 11.2.2.
my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "my-dialog",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "~11.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~11.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~11.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1101.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.2"
  }
}
```

I import some material modules in the app.module.ts file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { MatLoadingComponent } from './mat-loading/mat-loading.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { A11yModule } from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
import { ClipboardModule } from '@angular/cdk/clipboard';
import { DragDropModule } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import { PortalModule } from '@angular/cdk/portal';
import { ScrollingModule } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
import { CdkStepperModule } from '@angular/cdk/stepper';
import { CdkTableModule } from '@angular/cdk/table';
import { CdkTreeModule } from '@angular/cdk/tree';
import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { MatBadgeModule } from '@angular/material/badge';
import { MatBottomSheetModule } from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatButtonToggleModule } from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatChipsModule } from '@angular/material/chips';
import { MatStepperModule } from '@angular/material/stepper';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import {
  MatDialog,
  MatDialogModule,
  MatDialogRef,
  MAT_DIALOG_DATA,
  MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS,
} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatDividerModule } from '@angular/material/divider';
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';
import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatNativeDateModule, MatRippleModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatProgressBarModule } from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import { MatTreeModule } from '@angular/material/tree';
import { OverlayModule } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, MatLoadingComponent],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    A11yModule,
    ClipboardModule,
    CdkStepperModule,
    CdkTableModule,
    CdkTreeModule,
    DragDropModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatBottomSheetModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatTreeModule,
    OverlayModule,
    PortalModule,
    ScrollingModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS,
      useValue: { hasBackdrop: false },
    },
  ],
  entryComponents: [MatLoadingComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I want to open dialog from the app.component.ts file after 3s it automatically close but I got an error

```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatLoadingComponent } from './mat-loading/mat-loading.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'my-dialog';
  constructor(
    private dialogRef: MatDialog,
    private dialogCloseRef: MatDialogRef<MatLoadingComponent>
  ) {}

  viewModal() {
    this.dialogRef.open(MatLoadingComponent, {
      height: '60vh',
      width: '70vw',

      panelClass: 'panel-new-modal-dialog',
      autoFocus: false,
      disableClose: true,
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.dialogCloseRef.close();
    }, 3000);
  }
}
```

mat-loading-component.ts file

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mat-loading',
  templateUrl: './mat-loading.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mat-loading.component.scss'],
})
export class MatLoadingComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MatLoadingComponent>
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

when I open my browser got a Nullinjector error like this. Is there are any solutions to fix this error?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add `MatDialogRef` in your `app.module.ts` file's `providers` array, as

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS,
      useValue: { hasBackdrop: false },
    },
    MatDialogRef
  ]
```

Comment: I already try this way but I got an error